# Как превратить картинку в черно-белую в Qt?

Tags: цвета, изображения, преобразование, c++, qt

Здравствуйте!

Интересует вопрос, как сделать следующее:

Имеется цветная картинка в формате jpeg/png. Нужно написать программу, которая могла бы сделать из нее черно-белую и где-нибудь сохранить этот результат.
Все это нужно реализовать на C++ средствами Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека QT служит для построения графических интерфейсов, а не для манипулирования изображениями на низком уровне. Для преобразования цветной картинки в черно-белую надо использовать специальные алгоритмы или библиотеки.

Библиотеки можете сами посмотреть в интернете, что же касается алгоритмов:

[Seven grayscale conversion algorithms](http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/)

Меня в свое время устраивал простой luminance:

```
Gray = (Red * 0.3 + Green * 0.59 + Blue * 0.11)
```

То есть берете свое изображение с помощью того же QImage, вытаскиваете из него массив пикселей RGB и прогоняете каждый формулой (умножаете составляющие на коэффициенты). В итоге получается ЧБ изображение, с которым можно вести дальнейшую работу.

Comment: Необходимо использовать коэффициенты 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722. Ваши же [давно устарели](https://habrahabr.ru/post/304210/).

Answer (score 0):

QImage, вероятно, то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Да, но этого мало.
Потому что я первый раз сел за Qt и ни чуть не умею пользоваться его средствами. 
А обращаюсь сюда, дабы ускорить процесс реализации. Потому что времени на выполнение проекта не так много, как хотелось бы, а разбирать всю подноготную довольно долго.